# Calculating Covariance Matrix from pooled sum of squares and products about the mean?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, linear-algebra

I am given the following (labeled as the "pooled sum of squares and products about the mean"

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        x_1 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4\\
        x_1 & 19.1434 & 9.0356 &9.7634 & 2.2394 \\
        x_2 &  & 11.8638 & 4.6232 & 2.4746 \\
x_3 & & & 12.2978 & 3.8794\\
x_4 & & & & 2.4604
        \end{matrix}
$$

Do I simply divide the above by n-J to get my covariance matrix? Where n is the overall sample size and J is the number of treatments?

The procedure works as it should but I get a very large value that has me paranoid. I also don't understand what it means by "and products."